# How to open the FONT settings programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I know it is possible to invoke the device settings using action providers. However, I would like to invoke the FONT settings only.

I do not want to detected if the font was changed or not, only open the FONT settings menu.

Is there any way to do that avoiding creating my own implementation ?

Comment: Um, what are "the FONT settings"? I have not seen one in a Settings app.

Comment: if you go to : Settings -> Display -> Font Size

Answer (score 1):

"Settings -> Display -> Font Size" may not exist on all devices. Device manufacturers and ROM developers can customize the Settings app to their hearts' content.

At least on the Android 6.0 Nexus 5X I just tested, "Settings -> Display -> Font Size" is just a dialog. That is not independently launchable, because it is not an activity.

You are welcome to [use `ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS) to try to show the Display screen in Settings. The user still would have to tap on Font Size, and there may not be an activity that responds to that action string on all Android devices, as the documentation notes.

Comment: yeah.. I know about the device settings but it is not desirable.

Comment: Is there anything to open the advanced option on the display setting? I was trying to open it from ADB.